# Appetize.io App demo is not displaying image assets

Tags: ios

I have uploaded my .app file to Appetize.io and the application is running as expected, however all of the buttons in the application that use image assets are showing up as blank in the Appetize.io simulator. The button still works, just has no displayed image. I assume that my .app file does not include the assets folder, but I am not sure how to include these images so that Appetize.io can receive the image files.

Answer (score 1):

The appetize.io simulator is defaulted to iOS v11.4. I built the application for a 11.4 simulator version and reuploaded the app and that did the trick.